# how to download youtube video in the highest quality available

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, pytube

This code works perfectly, but I don't want the lowest quality. I want the highest one. When I tried changing the `video = youtube. streams.first()` to `video = youtube.streams.last()` I encountered a problem where the video that I downloaded was just a black screen with the audio playing in the background.

```
from tkinter import *
import pytube


# Functions
def download():
    video_url = url.get()
    try:
        youtube = pytube.YouTube(video_url)
        video = youtube.streams.first()
        video.download("C:/Users/iwanh/Desktop/MP4_MP3s")
        notif.config(fg="green", text="Download complete")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        notif.config(fg="red", text="Video could not be downloaded")


# Main Screen
master = Tk()
master.title("Youtube Video Downloader")

# Labels
Label(master, text="Youtube Video Converter", fg="red", font=("Calibri", 15)).grid(sticky=N, padx=100, row=0)
Label(master, text="Please enter the link to your video below : ", font=("Calibri", 15)).grid(sticky=N, row=1, pady=15)
notif = Label(master, font=("Calibri", 12))
notif.grid(sticky=N, pady=1, row=4)
# Vars
url = StringVar()
# Entry
Entry(master, width=50, textvariable=url).grid(sticky=N, row=2)
# Button
Button(master, width=20, text="Download", font=("Calibri", 12), command=download).grid(sticky=N, row=3, pady=15)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: PS. I also think it is because the video's extensions when I downloaded it when I had the `.last()` on was webm and not mp4

Comment: You may give more details in the black screen. e.g. Could it be a problem with your video player?

Comment: @zhh no i dont think so its a problem with my video player because when I get the lowest quality the video plays perfectly

Answer (score 4):

**Try To Use**

> get_highest_resolution()

**Instant Of Contact With Streams**

**This Func. Returns Highest Progressive Quality : )**

*May Be Checking The Documentation Will Help You Next Time : )*

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of streams

1- Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (**DASH**): save audio and video on the different tracks so you need to download both of them

2- **Progressive Stream**: save audio and video on the same track

The **Difference** is:

**Progressive Stream** is used only for resolutions **720p** and below

**DASH** for the **highest** quality streams

so if you need to download a resolution higher than 720p like 1080p
you must use DASH but you require to download both the audio and video tracks and then post-process them with software like FFmpeg to merge them.

According to the [Docs](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/streams.html#dash-vs-progressive-streams):

> some streams listed have both a video codec and audio codec, while others have just video or just audio, this is a result of YouTube supporting a streaming technique called Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH).

> In the context of pytube, the implications are for the highest quality streams; you now need to download both the audio and video tracks and then post-process them with software like FFmpeg to merge them.

> The legacy streams that contain the audio and video in a single file (referred to as “progressive download”) are still available, but only for resolutions 720p and below.

so now you can replace your code:

```py
video = youtube.streams.first()
```

with:

```py
video = youtube.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first().download()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
video = youtube.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
```

without the attribute "download()" will work well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).